# Perl Archive::Tar

Tags: perl

I want to archive all txt files with File::Find, delete the source files and remove empty directories.

I'm having difficulties renaming the files with '$tar->rename(  );' because I'd like to to strip them from their full path names and use only parent directory/*.txt, but whatever I try the code renames only one file.
I don't know where is the appropriate place to execute the 'unlink' function.

Thanks.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Archive::Tar;
use File::Find;
use File::Basename;  

my $dir = "E:/";

my @files = ();

find(\&archive, $dir);      
sub archive {
    /\.txt$/ or return;
    my $fd = $File::Find::dir;
    my $fn = $File::Find::name; 
    my $folder = basename($fd);
    my $file = $_;

    push @files, $fn;

    my $tar = Archive::Tar->new();  
    $tar->add_files(@files);
    $tar->rename( $fn, $folder."\\".$file );
    $tar->write($fd.'.tar');

    unlink $fn; 
    finddepth(sub{rmdir},'.');
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the File::Find interface incorrectly. The **archive** sub gets called once on every file found. You end up creating a new tar on every call, adding a single file to it and writing it out.

**Correction:** You end up trying to add all the previously found files, but you've already unlinked all except the last one.

Let's do this in small steps - first find and classify all .txt files according to directory, then add them to relevant tar files, and finally clean up:

```
my $dir = "E:/";

my %txt_files = ();

find(\&classify, $dir);      
sub classify{
    /\.txt$/ or return;
    my $fd = $File::Find::dir;
    my $fn = $File::Find::name;

    push @{$txt_files{$fd}||=[]}, $fn;
}

foreach my $folder (keys %txt_dirs) {
    my @files = @{$txt_files{$folder}};
    my $foldername = basename($folder);

    my $tar = Archive::Tar->new();  
    $tar->add_files(@files);
    $tar->rename( $_, $foldername."/".basename($_))
        for @files;

    $tar->write($folder.'.tar');
}

# remove all the txt files we've found
unlink for map {@{$_}} values %txt_files;

# try to remove the directories that contained the txt files
eval {rmdir} for keys %txt_files;
```

Comment: Great solution. That is exactly what I was looking for. Unlimited thanks.

Comment: indeed, very helpful.